# MS Access Substring

Tags: sql, ms-access, substring

I created a search Form for my db.
It works great, if you enter everything in 100% the same as the db has it stored.
What I want to change is the 100% part. If I enter "Jones" in the address tect box and hit search, I want "123 Jones", "497 Jones", etc. to appear in my query. 
Is it possible to do this?

This is my code. Only thing missing is more of the same basic if statements.

```
ElseIf sA <> "" Then

qry = "Address"

DoCmd.OpenQuery qry
```

Edit: This is the SQL

```
SELECT [Service Calls].[Project Name], [Service Calls].[Service Address], [Service Calls].[Date of Service], [Service Calls].[Type of Call], [Service Calls].Technician, [Service Calls].[Total Billed], [Service Calls].[Zip Code], [Service Calls].[Description of Work], [Forms]![Search]![sA] AS Expr1
FROM [Service Calls]
WHERE ((([Forms]![Search]![sA])=[Service Calls]![Service Address]));
```

Comment: You'd need to provide additional information to get the answer, but I believe you're looking to use `like` instead of `=` in your Address query.

Comment: qry is just a variable to hold the name of query I want the button to open. I can also post my sql if it helps.

Comment: Yes, paste your sql. What you are looking for is something along the lines of `WHERE ... AND Table.Column Like "*" & [Input].[Text] & "*"`

Comment: @luk2302 If memory serves me correctly, you are probably gonna need some single quotes in there.

Comment: @Newd depends on where you define it: In VBA yes, in the query editor no.

Comment: And btw: @ChrisVachon you need to learn how to use SO - you have asked quite a lot of question and have yet to accept a valid answer for most of them. I will not provide anymore of an answer until you change that situation. [How to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @luk2302 I have accepted some answers and posted my SQL in the original post

Comment: Turn the arguments of the where clause around and insert the like clause I posted above instead of the =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM [Service Calls]
WHERE ([Service Calls].[Service Address]) LIKE "*" & ([Forms]![Search]![sA]) & "*";
```

The `*` is a placeholder for anything. Pre- and appending it will result in a `LIKE` query matching every string that contains your search phrase `[Forms]![Search]![sA]` anywhere in it.